# Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'UIButton?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to hide a button, until another condition is met. When i load the app i am using the slider and when it reaches the max, it should make the button visible, but for some weird reason it won't. I have just done it in another app with no issues and the code is almost identical.?

Can't figure out what to do tbh.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    profileVisible.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) { 

    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) { (motion, error) in DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.slider.value = Float((motion?.attitude.roll ?? 0 ) * 1.4)

        print(self.slider.value)

        if self.slider.value == 1.0 {
            self.profileVisible = false
            self.motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()


            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); // vibrates when payment has succeded
        }

        if self.slider.value == -1.0 {
           profileVisible = true
            self.motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss setting here

```
if self.slider.value == 1.0 {
    self.profileVisible = false
```

And here

```
if self.slider.value == -1.0 {
     profileVisible = true
```

Should be

```
profileVisible.isHidden = true/false // set it's value according to your logic
```

`profileVisible` is of type `UIButton` you need to set it's `isHidden` property not it directly

Comment: Wow, I forgot ishidden...have been coding for the last 10 hours, thanks for the help!